# Android: Mediaplayer keeps playing in background. How to stop it?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer

I have developed an Android app, where the user can play a sound by clicking on a button, in a certain fragment. However, when you exit this fragment or close the app it keeps playing. How do I stop it if one exits the fragment or closes the app?

This is how I play the sound:

```
public class PageFragment_Bon extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

    private int mPage;
    private Button start, stop, replay;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    int [] filer = new int[18];


    public static PageFragment_Bon newInstance(int page) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        PageFragment_Bon fragment = new PageFragment_Bon();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
           }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_boenner, container, false);

        start = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.start);
        start.setOnClickListener(this);

        stop = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.stop);
        stop.setOnClickListener(this);

        replay = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.replay);
        replay.setOnClickListener(this);

         if(filer[mPage] != 0){
            start.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            replay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getBaseContext(), filer[mPage]);
        }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v == start){
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }

        else if(v == stop){
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }

        else if(v == replay){
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H123, you need to handle in onPause() and onResume() event in Fragment.

**OnPause :**

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();

    if(mediaplayer != null)
    {
         mediaplayer.pause();
         media_length = mediaplayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }

}
```

**OnResume :**

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    if(mediaplayer != null)
    {
        mediaplayer.seekTo(media_length);
        mediaplayer.start();
    }

}
```

Change your onClick method like below,

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(mediaPlayer == null)
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getBaseContext(), filer[mPage]);//add this line
    if(v == start){
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    else if(v == stop){
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    else if(v == replay){
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I put in 'OnClick();' Now it starts playing automatically

Comment: you remove creating mediaplayer obj in onCreate  mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getBaseContext(), filer[mPage]); and add this line in onclick

Comment: now i update my answer see above change your onClick like this

Comment: Thanks! :) I want to ask you, how do I make it in such way that the sound only plays when the relevant fragment in open? You know, if I start one and switch to another fragment page (in the same activity), it doesn't stop playing