# How to stop mediaplayer in broadcastreceiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-mediaplayer

I have a broadcast receiver in android. I am triggering media player in the background, how to stop the media player in the background

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43823306/android-mediaplayer-keeps-playing-in-background-how-to-stop-it

Comment: Actually I am triggering the mediaplayer when the app is completely closed and a notification is generated to the user along with sound, now I have to stop the player from the app, how to do it ?

Comment: can you edit your post with code snippet, with some details ?